# A grammar expression for representing comma-delimited lists

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

Based on my experience, formal grammars typically express comma-delimited lists in a form similar to this:

```
foo_list -> foo ("," foo)*
```

What alternatives are there to avoid mentioning `foo` twice? Although this contrived example may seem innocent enough, I am encountering non-trivial expressions instead of `foo`. For example:

```
foo_list -> ( ( bar | baz | cat ) ) ( "," ( bar | baz | cat ) )*
```

Comment: Why not create a non-terminal with the non-trivial expression: a -> bar | baz | cat?

Comment: @fbafelipe: I agree that a non-terminal would typically be a good solution. However, in my case, I was hoping to avoid inventing names for these new non-terminals (there are many of them and they sometimes appear within nested expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember a (proprietary) parser generator that I once worked with, which would have this production written as

```
foo_list ::= <* bar | baz | cat ; "," *>
```

Yes, exactly like that. The actual metacharacters above are disputable, but I deem the general approach acceptable.

When writing another parser generator, I considered something alike for a while, but dropped it in favor of keeping the model simple.

A syntax diagram of course can nicely represent it without the unwanted repetition:

[image: foo_list]

Answer (score 0):

During my experimentation, this syntax showed some potential:

```
foo_list -> ( bar | baz | cat ) ("," ...)*
```

The `...` token refers to the preceding expression (in this case, `( bar | baz | cat )`).

This is not a perfect solution, but I am putting it out there for discussion.